# Difficulty using Python's socket.gethostbyaddr()

Tags: python, networking, dig, python-sockets, gethostbyaddr

I am trying to reverse dns a list of IPs using `socket.gethostbyaddr()` in python, which returns 'Unknown Host' for some values, but using `dig` for the same ip returns the Hostname. Also, `dig` seems to be significantly faster than using python module, is there any specific reasons for that?

```
import socket

# This returns 'Unknown Host' 
name, alias, addresslist = socket.gethostbyaddr('114.143.51.197')
```

Comment: gethostbyaddr works fine for me when I reverse 4.2.2.2.  Please post code that has the problem

Comment: import socket
name,alias,addresslist = socket.gethostbyaddr('114.143.51.197')

This returns 'Unknown Host'

whereas dig -x 114.143.51.197+short
gives me the hostname.

The nameserver for DNS resolution I used are 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, still no luck.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832264/difficulty-using-pythons-socket-gethostbyaddr/8225878#comment9550464_7832264)...

> whereas dig -x 114.143.51.197+short gives me the hostname.

I'm sorry, but you are mistaken.  114.143.51.197 does not have a PTR record... therefore `socket.gethostbyaddr()` should throw an error... To process this use-case correctly, add a `try` / `except` clause that traps [`socket.herror`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.herror)

```
>>> def dns_ptr_lookup(addr):
...     try:
...         return socket.gethostbyaddr(addr)
...     except socket.herror:
...         return None, None, None
...
>>> # At this time, 4.2.2.2 has a valid PTR
>>> name,alias,addresslist = dns_ptr_lookup('4.2.2.2')
>>> print(name)
vnsc-bak.sys.gtei.net
>>>
>>> # At this time, 114.143.51.197 does NOT have a valid PTR
>>> name,alias,addresslist = dns_ptr_lookup('114.143.51.197')
>>> print(name)
None
>>>
```

DNS reverse lookup for 114.143.51.197... note that it does not have a valid `PTR` record

```
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ dig @8.8.8.8 -x 114.143.51.197

; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R4 <<>> @8.8.8.8 -x 114.143.51.197
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 4735
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;197.51.143.114.in-addr.arpa.   IN      PTR

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
114.in-addr.arpa.       1800    IN      SOA     ns1.apnic.net. read-txt-record-of-zone-first-dns-admin.apnic.net. 17812 7200 1800 604800 172800

;; Query time: 182 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Tue Nov 22 05:11:36 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 134

[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ python
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Jan 24 2010, 14:53:14)
[GCC 4.3.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket
>>> socket.gethostbyaddr('114.143.51.197')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
socket.herror: (1, 'Unknown host')
>>>
```

This is what a valid `PTR` record should look like...

```
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ dig -x 4.2.2.2

; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R4 <<>> -x 4.2.2.2
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 61856
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 3, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;2.2.2.4.in-addr.arpa.          IN      PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
2.2.2.4.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN      PTR     vnsc-bak.sys.gtei.net.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
2.4.in-addr.arpa.       86400   IN      NS      dnsauth2.sys.gtei.net.
2.4.in-addr.arpa.       86400   IN      NS      dnsauth1.sys.gtei.net.
2.4.in-addr.arpa.       86400   IN      NS      dnsauth3.sys.gtei.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
dnsauth1.sys.gtei.net.  1800    IN      A       4.2.49.2

;; Query time: 308 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Nov 22 05:10:16 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 158

[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ python
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Jan 24 2010, 14:53:14)
[GCC 4.3.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket
>>> socket.gethostbyaddr('4.2.2.2')
('vnsc-bak.sys.gtei.net', [], ['4.2.2.2'])
>>>
```

Comment: I get it.. I thought dig was providing me hostname whereas it wasnt. Thanks