# Not able to print hostname

Tags: python

I have a Python code that connects to MongoDB and extracts data - when I print the same I get the below output:

```
data =  db.collection.aggregate(...)

for d in data:
       ip = d['_id']
       print d , ip


{u'count': 125391, u'_id': u'11.11.11.111'} 11.11.11.111
{u'count': 994883, u'_id': u'11.11..11.112'} 11.11..11.112
..............................................
```

But when I try to get the hostname for the IP listed in each records I get the below error:

```
name,alias,addresslist = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./myprog.py", line 51, in <module>
    name,alias,addresslist = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)
socket.herror: [Errno 0] Resolver Error 0 (no error)
```

Answer (score 0):

`11.11.11.111`, etc. do not look like valid ip addresses, so that would be the first issue I think you should try solving.

Where are these ip addresses coming from?

Comment: Well I just gave a dummy value the values are correct and when I do a nslookup of that IP I do get a valid correct result

Comment: @Prakash You sure?

    $ nslookup 11.11.11.111
    Server:  192.168.1.1
    Address: 192.168.1.1#53

    ** server can't find 111.11.11.11.in-addr.arpa.: NXDOMAIN

Comment: As stated I have dummy IP values - 11.11.11.111 - in actual I get valid one only. I found more about issue and fix in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832264/difficulty-using-pythons-socket-gethostbyaddr however at one point of time I am again facing this error - socket.error: wildcard resolved to multiple address

Comment: @Prakash, if your IP addresses are valid than there shouldn't be any problem with validation. It's not a MongoDB issue. I'd suggest you to update your post with minimum viable and reproducible solution. Providing a dummy value will not help anyone. For testing purpose, try using google.com ip address and see if it works.