# socket.gethostbyaddr returns unknown host

Tags: python, linux, dns, fqdn

I want to get the fqdn from the hostname.
I am am executiong this command on a linux server:
python -c "import sys, socket; sys.stdout.write(socket.gethostbyaddr('')[0])"
THis command works well and returns the fqdn from the hostname. But for some other servers, it returns this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
socket.herror: [Errno 1] Unknown host

When i do "host " linux command, I get the fqdn of the failed host names with python command.

Anyone have a solution for that plz?

Comment: I got 3 IP on same interface and got 5 service. You want get host name but which interface(or clone interface) is current ? Define an ip address before getting hostname. Use `netifaces` module...

Answer (score 2):

[Difficulty using Python's socket.gethostbyaddr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832264/difficulty-using-pythons-socket-gethostbyaddr) covers this nicely.

The gist is that you must verify there's a PTR record. If not, you'll have to handle it via a try, except clause.

Specifically look at the part comparing the a valid and non-valid PTR records.

Comment: My input wasn't an IP address but it was the hostname without the domain. Just the server name.